# Cross domain contents reading with ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I want to read div contents from cross domain. for example i want to load the content from the following URL:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727098.aspx
```

there is div in this page with **ID="mainBody"**. i have tried the following code but its return only 200 success in the div while shows an error in firefox console that:

```
 SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

The code i am trying is the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#d").html('Loading wait...');
    $.ajax({
        url:"https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727098.aspx#mainBody",
        type:"POST",
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
        async:true,
        crossDomain:true,
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success: function(txt){
            $("#d").text(txt);
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            $("#d").html(xhr.status+" "+xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: not possible. jsonp requires cooperation from the server you're hitting. you can NOT use jsonp to fetch random html.

Comment: Setting JSONP does not magically allow cross domain calls to go through, the other side needs to support it. Unless MSDN has [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) set, you are not going to be able to do this from the clientside.

Comment: i think there must be some way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you get is **not** `"jsonp"`, as you have given `dataType: "jsonp"`, the browser expects it to be JavaScript and finds out it starts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And in JavaScript `<` as a starting character is a syntax error. You need to remove the following line:

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

This way of communication with external domains is possible only by those allow you to get `JSONp` from their website.

The main reason is that, the browser after receiving the response, tries to execute it as a JavaScript, which fails making all the subsequent scripts to fail too.

---

You need to use a **Server Side Script** like Proxy PHP file, that reads the content and executes it correctly.

`Proxy.php`:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    die(file_get_contents($_GET["url"]));
?>
```

And call it like this:

```
url: "proxy.php?url=https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727098.aspx"
```

Comment: And the call will still fail... And JSONP is not the only way.

Comment: @epascarello I have said that. `This way of communication with external domains is possible only by those allow you to get JSONp from their website.` Please note. `:)`

Comment: [JSONP is not the only way...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: I remove the dataType: "Jsonp" and now its return "0 error".

Comment: Because of the Same Origin Policay and the lack of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Ok, i agree with you, but is there no any hack or other way to get it enable without target host permissions? (I know it will be a crime, but just need to konw)

Comment: @AbdulRahman You can do it using a Proxy Script from your server. Say you have a PHP and you can use `file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/")` and send it to your side. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar You are right, but this will get all the content from the target url and by means of this, the page will take too much time on load? what do you think?

Comment: You are bypassing a basic security. These have to be compromised. LoL, you cannot just like that hack into the Swiss Bank! `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar its Interesting, while i am in search of to do as i think, and i hope i will find some way with some programming language or utility...

Comment: Why do you need to find "some" way. Why not use the way I said? Make a proxy script.

Comment: Oh sure i am reading the same, and ok boss i got very good idea from your answer "Proxy Script": thanks